# How can I keep a view controller in memory after its popped from the stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pass-by-value

This is an embarrassingly simple question, but I need to preserve a view controller and my current solution is not a solution.

I have a slide out table view menu that lets me select a new view controller to push to the forefront. When I select a view, it deallocs the old main view controller to push the new one. Since 90% of my functionality revolves around one view controller, I want it to stay in memory so I don't have to constantly spend resources to allocate it and either pull the last data source from core data or make a network request.

I naively tried to set a placeholder `temporaryMainViewController` and assign it to my center view controller before it is assigned another VC, but assigning the current main view controller to the `temporaryMainViewController` simply assigns the address of the main view controller- so when it's changed, so is my tempVC. 
Trying to `copy` the view controller causes a crash.

So how can I effectively do `self.temporaryMainViewController = self.currentCenterViewController;` where the temp controller is assigned by value of object and not value of address?

-- EDIT --
More info:

[ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) keeps (in my case) 3 controllers in memory- the top/center/main view controller, a left hidden controller, and a right hidden controller. My left hidden controller is a tableview, `LeftMenuTableViewController` , where each row, when selected, observes the view controller class I've associated with that indexPath then instantiates an instance of that class and sets it to the topViewController with a simple assignment statement. I want to keep only my *initial* top view controller (of class `PlacesNavigationViewController` (which holds `PlacesTableViewController`)) in memory when a new view controller is assigned to the top view.

My first approach was to declare a placeholder property in `LeftMenuTableViewController`, since it never leaves memory itself.

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* temporaryViewController;`

then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
// make local variables for storyboard and the identifier of the view controller that will be pushed, then..
self.temporaryViewController = self.topViewController;
self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:newViewControllerIdentifier];
```

but this fails because the temporary controller is assigned the memory address of the topViewController- which in the next line is given a new view controller to hold.

So what I need is a way to hold the contents of `topViewController` so that when `topViewController` changes, I still have the old VC in memory.

I'm likely forgetting some obvious tenet of Objective-C, but this is giving a good bit of trouble. Let me know if I did not make something clear.

Comment: maybe I'm missing the obvious, but why not just retain it?

Comment: Yeah, `[vc retain]` does the job. (Equivalent under ARC: keep a `strong` reference to it.)

Comment: I *do* have a strong reference to it. But when I assign a new object to the top view controller, the tempViewController still points to whatever is at the memory address behind the topVC.

Comment: You need to provide a little more context and code for people to be able to help you. Your controller hierarchy would be a useful thing to tell us.

Comment: @rdelmar - Added more context. Let me know if I'm omitting something important.

Comment: I don't know if something is going on with ECSlidingViewController, but setting temporaryVC to self.topVC, and then reassigning topVC to another controller, shouldn't make topVC and temporaryVC point to the same thing.

Comment: I am using a different sliding menu library but having exactly this issue, did you ever resolve it?  I would appreciate if you could share an update!

Answer (score -1):

You want to use `viewControllers` property of UINavigationController class. The documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers). Basically, you can just swap 2 view controllers in viewControllers array and then use `setViewControllers:animated:` to make the transition.

Hope this helps!
Cheers!